# Using /etc/fstab to add a mount as a user (VirtualBox, centos)

Tags: centos, virtualbox, mount, fstab

I'm mounting my mac folder as a share in virtualBox CentOS6 machine with the following command:

```
mount -t vboxsf git /mnt/git/ -o uid=500,gid=500
```

It works perfectly but I can't figure out how to make this happen automatically on boot. I can't seem to spot any way to specify the user (in this case 500) and group (again, 500) that I do in the command line for /etc/fstab

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
/fullpathto/git /mnt/git/ uid=500,gid=500,umask=0022 0 0
```

I'm doing this off the top of my head so it's untested.